# How to pass array into controller in laravel using ajax

Tags: arrays, ajax, laravel

I just need to know how to pass a array using ajax into a laravel controller and save those data in DB. I tried serveral ways. but the serve respond is Object { error: "No data received"}. API status code is 200.

This is my ajax code.
function AddContactData() {

```
var contactData = [];
var table = document.getElementById('customer_contact'),
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
    i, j, cells, customerId;

for (i = 0, j = rows.length; i < j; ++i) {
    cells = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    if (!cells.length) {
        continue;
    }
    var data = {
       
        "name": cells[0].childNodes[0].value,
        "designation": cells[1].childNodes[0].value,
        "mobile": cells[2].childNodes[0].value,
        "fixed": cells[3].childNodes[0].value,
        "email": cells[4].childNodes[0].value,
        "remark": cells[5].childNodes[0].value
    };
    contactData.push(data);



}
//console.log(contactData);

 var contactDetails = JSON.stringify(contactData);
 console.log(contactData);
$.ajax({
    url: '/saveContact',
    type:'POST',
    data: contactDetails,
    headers:{
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
     success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        
       // $('#frmCustomer')[0].reset();
    }, error: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }

})
```

};

and this is my laravel function to insert those data to DB

public function addContactDetails(Request $request){

```
   try{
    $data = json_decode($request->input('contactDetails'), true);
    if(empty($data)){
        return response()->json(['error' => 'No data received']); 
    }
    foreach($data as $key =>$value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            foreach($value as $row){
                DB::table('customer_contacts')->insert([
                    'customer_id' => 1,
                     'contact_person'=> $row['name'],
                     'designation'=>$row['designation'],
                     'mobile'=>$row['mobile'],
                     'fixed'=>$row['fixed'],
                     'email'=>$row['email'],
                     'remarks'=>$row['remark']

                ]);

            }
        }
        return response()->json(["status" => true]);
    }
   }catch(Exception $ex){
    if ($ex instanceof ValidationException) {
        return response()->json(["ValidationException" => ["id" => collect($ex->errors())->keys()[0], "message" => $ex->errors()[collect($ex->errors())->keys()[0]]]]);
    }
    return response()->json(["error" => $ex]);

   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need  JOSN decode in this case because laravel will convert the object to PHP array automatically
try this

```
$validator = validator($request->all(), [
'ids' => 'required|array',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
return [
'errors' => $validator->errors()->toArray()
];
}
dump($validator->validated()['ids']);
```

and to see the data in your console i advice you to use this package [laravel-dump-server/installation](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-dump-server/installation)